# TradingView add data dynamically

Tags: android, tradingview-api

Good day everyone!

I started work with [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts).

How can I add and update bars from an Android app programmatically? What me need send in `webView.evaluateJavascript(...)` ?

I am use Technical Analysis Charts.

Comment: I hope you got that ?